# Django queryset seach function isn't working. Returns unfiltered results

Tags: python, django, search, filter

I' trying to implement a search function but when I enter a query into the search bar it doesn't filter anything and returns everything as is, unfiltered.

forum\views.py

```
def forum(request):
 context = {}

 # passing the query to the search bar
 query = ""
 if request.GET:
      query = request.GET['q']
      context['query'] = str(query)

 posts = sorted(get_forum_queryset(query), key=attrgetter('created_at'), reverse=True)

 return render(request, 'forum/discussion-forum.html')

def get_forum_queryset(query=None):
     queryset = []
     queries = query.split(" ")
     for  q in queries:
          posts = Post.objects.filter(
               Q(title__icontains=q) |
               Q(contents__icontains=q) |
               Q(tag__icontains=q)
          ).distinct()

          for post in posts:
               queryset.append(post)

     return list(set(queryset))
```

core\templates\core\base.html

```
<div class="search-bar">
  <form class="form-inline" method="GET">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class='bx bx-search' ></i></span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Search" id="id_q">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

In order to set the value to {{query}} to the input attribute, I set the value using javascript because it wasn't working when I did so in the html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("id_q").value = "{{query}}"
</script>
```

forum\templates\forum\discussion-forum.html

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

{% if posts %}
{% for post in posts %}
  # post the posts
{% endfor %}

{%else%}
<div class="container content-section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card m-auto">
      <div class="card-body mt-2 mb-2">
        <h2 class="card-title"> No results found </h2>
        <p class="card-body">
          Thre were no results matching your search: "{{query}}"
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

My searchbar returns this when I input something into the search bar and enter. e.g, I entered 'python' here.

http://localhost:8000/forum/discussion-forum/?q=python

I have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you see all records from your database, correct?

Comment: Yes, all the records are outputed unfiltered.

Comment: Before I edited the script tp what is shown now in my question my context was
     context = {
          'posts': get_forum_queryset(query)
     }    It also showed all of the posts unfiltered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [**`request.method == 'GET'`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method) - [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method)

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.shortcuts import render
import operator
from functools import reduce

def forum(request):
    context = {}

    # passing the query to the search bar
    query = ""
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = request.GET.get("q", "")
        context['query'] = query
    queries = query.split(" ")
    context["posts"] = Post.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(title__icontains=x) | Q(contents__icontains=x) | Q(tag__icontains=x) for x in queries))).order_by('-created_at').distinct()

    return render(request, 'forum/discussion-forum.html', context)
```

You can also use `reduce` and `operator.or_` to filter your objects (see example above).

Comment: It unfortunately did not work. I'm still geting the same incorrect results.

Comment: @ImmortalNoob, What are you seeing if you `print(request.GET)` in your view?

Comment: @ImmortalNoob, i updated my answer with `reduce` and `operator.or_`

Comment: I implemented  `print(request.GET)` but it did not return anything. But my url shows that the variable q is being assigned what I'm entering into the search bar. I also tried your updated code too, it didn't work either.